# Bad Access error when calling Swift closure from C api in Cocoa

Tags: swift, closures, interop, function-pointers

I'm trying to implement a "file copy with progress" in Swift on macOS.
After lots of searching I just found [rustle's implement in Objective-C](https://github.com/rustle/RSTLCopyOperation).
It works pretty fine. 
But I would like it "swifty".
I tried it with some simplified code:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var copyfileCallback: copyfile_callback_t = {(what, stage, state, sourcePath, destPath, context) -> Int32 in
        return COPYFILE_CONTINUE
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let src = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "Source_File_Path").fileSystemRepresentation
        let dst = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "Destination_File_Path").fileSystemRepresentation
        let flag: copyfile_flags_t = UInt32(COPYFILE_ALL)

        let state = copyfile_state_alloc()

        // If I implement this, the copyfile() method will complain "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2..." error
        copyfile_state_set(state, UInt32(COPYFILE_STATE_STATUS_CB), &copyfileCallback)

        copyfile(src, dst, state, flag)
    }
}
```

The basic function `copyfile()` works fine. But if I implement the callback function by providing a pointer of `copyfileCallback` closure to `copyfile_state_set()`, then `copyfile()` just complains "Bad_Access...".
I guess maybe the closure was released before the C api tries to access it.
But I have no idea how to solve this problem...
Any clue will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
copyfile_state_set(state, UInt32(COPYFILE_STATE_STATUS_CB), &copyfileCallback)
```

because is passes the *address* of the `copyfileCallback` variable to the function, not the function pointer itself. In C you can pass an arbitrary function as a `void *` argument. In Swift you have to cast the function to a pointer explicitly:

```
let state = copyfile_state_alloc()
copyfile_state_set(state, UInt32(COPYFILE_STATE_STATUS_CB),
                   unsafeBitCast(copyfileCallback, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self))
```

And don't forget to release the memory eventually, after the copy operation:

```
copyfile_state_free(state)
```

*Remark:* In Swift it is recommended to use the (value overlay type) `URL` instead of `NSURL`:

```
let srcURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "Source_File_Path")
let destURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "Destination_File_Path")

let result = srcURL.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { srcFile in
    destURL.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { destFile in
        copyfile(srcFile, destFile, state, flag)
    }
}
```

Comment: It works like charm. Thank you very much, and thanks for the enlightening remarks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Martin's valid answer, you can also pass your class's instance (self) as. the 'context' with COPYFILE_STATE_STATUS_CTX.

So supposing your class is called 'Copier' and its callback function is called 'asyncCallback', you'd set it up like this - and release the class's state variable with copyfile_state_free in its deinit'

```
    private func createState () throws {
        guard let state = copyfile_state_alloc() else {
            throw CopyFileError.cantCreateState
        }

        let callback: copyfile_callback_t = { what, stage, state, src, dst, context in
          let obj = Unmanaged<Copier>.fromOpaque(context!).takeUnretainedValue()
          return obj.asyncCallback(what: what, stage: stage, state: state!, src: src, dst: dst)
        }

        copyfile_state_set(state, UInt32(COPYFILE_STATE_STATUS_CB), unsafeBitCast(callback, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self))

        let context = Unmanaged.passUnretained(self)
        copyfile_state_set(state, UInt32(COPYFILE_STATE_STATUS_CTX), context.toOpaque())

        self.state = state
    }
```